# Outlook Dev Center - OAuth Sandbox stopped working with mail

Tags: oauth, outlook, sandbox, office365api

Outlook Dev Center - OAuth Sandbox stoped working with mail. When i try to send :

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages?$top=10
```

i'm getting :

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
request-id: 72bb8456-b708-4395-b20b-070f59203571
X-CalculatedBETarget: AM4PR06MB1602.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 403
x-ms-diagnostics: 2000008;reason="The token contains not enough scope to make this call.";error_category="invalid_grant"
OData-Version: 4.0
X-DiagInfo: AM4PR06MB1602
X-BEServer: AM4PR06MB1602
X-FEServer: AM4PR01CA0018
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: C76DC482B3B948DCA89EA29991DAC69F Ref B:CFF0022456998571B7B1C5143CD90D48 Ref C: Sun Oct 30 05:12:00 2016 PST
Cache-Control: private
Date: Sun, 30 Oct 2016 12:12:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=7f60ed49643e4ce098a0af5830de4eec; expires=Mon, 30-Oct-2017 12:12:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer client_id="00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",   trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*",    token_types="app_asserted_user_v1 service_asserted_app_v1",   error="invalid_token"
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

{
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
   }
}
```

after some investigation i noticed that OAuth Sandbox is not requesting email read write permission.
Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't reproduce this. The Sandbox does request read/write permission via the `Mail.ReadWrite.Shared` scope, assuming you are authorizing with your own account.

If you click the `Authorize using Sandbox Account` it only requests `Mail.Read.Shared`, but that is sufficient scope to do a `GET` on `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages?$top=10`.

<s>So to answer your question, no, I don't believe this is a bug. :) Can you provide more info on exactly what you're doing when you get this error? Are you logging in with an Office 365 account or a Microsoft account (outlook.com, Hotmail.com, etc.)?</s>

**Update**: The problem was caused by Microsoft accounts not understanding the `Mail.ReadWrite.Shared` and ignoring it. The sandbox has been updated to request both the `Mail.ReadWrite` and the `Mail.ReadWrite.Shared` scopes.

Comment: Hey @jason-johnston, thank you for quick response. I'm trying to connect using an outlook account and live account. I received                                      [this](http://i.imgur.com/We1EXGb.png) permissions page and after accepting [these](http://i.imgur.com/INlQZO1.png) are the permissions that listed under a sandbox application

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the added detail. I think I know what's going on, I'll try to get this fixed today.

Comment: This should be fixed now, please let me know if not.